# resource api not found in mvc application

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-web-api

In existing MVC application I have added api support.
Added api controller but when i hit url it shows error -

> The resource cannot be found.

I tried url -

```
https://localhost:44316/api/getdata
https://localhost:44316/Test/api/getdata
```

TestController.cs

```
public class TestController : ApiController
    {
        [HttpGet]
        [Route("api/getdata")]
        public IEnumerable<string> GetData()
        {
            return new string[] { "value1", "value2" };
        }
    }
```

WebApiConfig.cs

```
public static class WebApiConfig
    {
        public static void Register(HttpConfiguration config)
        {
            config.MapHttpAttributeRoutes();

            config.Routes.MapHttpRoute(
                name: "DefaultApi",
                routeTemplate: "api/{controller}/{id}",
                defaults: new { id = RouteParameter.Optional }
            );
        }
    }
```

RouteConfig.cs

```
 public class RouteConfig
    {
        public static void RegisterRoutes(RouteCollection routes)
        {
            routes.IgnoreRoute("{resource}.axd/{*pathInfo}");

            routes.MapRoute(
                name: "Default",
                url: "{controller}/{action}/{id}",
                defaults: new { controller = "Home", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional }
            );
        }
    }
```

Comment: Did you actually call WebApiConfig.Register?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If this is an existing MVC application, then you need to register your web api routes. You need to add this line of code to *Global.asax.cs* to register your web api routes in `Application_Start` method:

```
GlobalConfiguration.Configure(WebApiConfig.Register);
```

Once you do that, your URLs should then work.

Comment: Wouldn't this be if `config.MapHttpAttributeRoutes();` wasn't called and the method had not been applied `[Route("api/getdata")]`?

Comment: @Neo It works for me. Are you sure you do not have any other settings?

Comment: this is mvc applcation not web api project and in mvc app into controller folder i have added this new API controller this is what i did

Comment: do i need to register into app start like this ? GlobalConfiguration.Configure(WebApiConfig.Register);

Answer (score -1):

The Route attribute is in wrong place, it should decorate the Controller class.

Try this:

```
[Route("api/[controller]")]
public class TestController : ApiController
{
    [HttpGet]
    public IEnumerable<string> GetData()
    {
        return new string[] { "value1", "value2" };
    }
}
```

and call Get http://localhost:XXXX/api/test.

Comment: Not really, you can decorate a controller or an action as you wish